# Remote access to server via service control panel for non-admin user in Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, service, user-permissions

I'm trying to configure my Windows 2008 servers so that my developers can view their status without needing to log on to the box or be an admin. Unfortunately, the permissions set in Windows 2008 for remote non-admin users don't include the ability to enumerate or otherwise query services. This causes anything that contacts the SCM on the far end to fail (Win32_Service, sc.exe, services.msc etc).

How do I set up permissions so that they can at least list the services and see if they are running?

Comment: Hi -- did you resolve this? We're trying to do similar so we can do a remote WMI (e.g. `wmic /node:server services list`) to no avail. WMI perms are good as we can do remote WMI queries on other namespaces/classes without issue.

Comment: Hah -- sorted. See below :-)

Answer (score 1):

After some googling around today, I found [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907460/en-us). It *seems* to work so far, even though the security descriptor is for Windows Server 2003. I've found you can do `sc sdshow SCMANAGER` to get the current value so when back in the office tomorrow I'll be comparing an contrasting to make sure I've not locked something out I shouldn't have :-)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be [PSList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) running every minute via scheduled task and dumping to a text file available via IIS.

This might be applicable: *[How to grant users rights to manage services in Windows 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288129/en-us/)*.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/alunj/archive/2006/02/13/83472.aspx) article about security descriptor definition language (SDDL) in relation to Windows services security. 
Hope you'll find a combination of access control parameters which satisfy all your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable non administrators to use the SCM or any other MMC snap-in by editing Group Policies. Maybe [this Microsoft KB entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271135/en-us) will help you.

> ...without needing to log on to the box or be an admin...

This won't be possible, because windows uses authorisation on nearly every interface, also connection through an MMC snap-in will require authorisation.

Comment: Access to the MMC itself is not the issue - I'm talking about remoteaccess to the SCM subsystem.